Flutter HTML use .fromTextStyle and custom tag settings
We have theming setup in our app and so we are using the HTML widget shown below. It's working great using .fromTextStyle to apply styling, which works great with BuildContext as well as being able to remove padding and margins for elements. What I'm having trouble figuring out is combing the two while still keeping the ability to use our custom theming.
Our current code:
    return Html(
      data: '<p>$excerpt</p>',
      style: {
        "p": Style.fromTextStyle(context.textTheme.regular.bodyMDSerif),
        "body": Style(
          padding: HtmlPaddings.zero,
          margin: Margins.zero,
        ),
      },
    );

What I'd like to do is something like:
    return Html(
      data: '<p>$excerpt</p>',
      style: {
        "p": Style( // Apply custom theming AND removing padding/margins
          textStyle: context.textTheme.regular.bodyMDSerif,
          padding: HtmlPaddings.zero,
          margin: Margins.zero,
        )
        "body": Style(
          padding: HtmlPaddings.zero,
          margin: Margins.zero,
        ),
      },
    );

Any suggestions on how to do this?

You can use the copyWith method of the Style class:
return Html(
  data: '<p>$excerpt</p>',
  style: {
    "p": Style.fromTextStyle(context.textTheme.regular.bodyMDSerif).copyWith(
      padding: HtmlPaddings.zero,
      margin: Margins.zero,
    ),
    "body": Style(
      padding: HtmlPaddings.zero,
      margin: Margins.zero,
    ),
  },
);

